# How to Store Large Data in Laravel Session

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm facing an issue while trying to handle large error collections during an import process in Laravel. I'm attempting to store a serialized error collection in the session, but when the collection size exceeds a certain limit, it doesn't get stored due to memory constraints (i guess).

Here's the code:

```
 public function import(Request $request)
    {
       // ... other codes

        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $import = new EmployeeImport;
            Excel::import($import, $request->file('file_attachment'));

            if ($import->failures()->isNotEmpty()) {
                $errors = collect();
                foreach ($import->failures() as $failure) {
                    $rowNumber = $failure->row();
                    $attribute = $failure->attribute();
                    $errorMessages = $failure->errors();

                    $errors->push([
                        'rowNumber' => $rowNumber,
                        'attribute' => $attribute,
                        'messages' => $errorMessages,
                    ]);
                }

                DB::rollBack();
                $serializedCollection = serialize($errors);
                // dd($serializedCollection); // passed  
                return redirect()->route('employee.index')->with('import_error', $serializedCollection);
            }

            // ...
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
           // ... catch any error
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using Laravel's `with()` method to pass a serialized error collection (`$serializedCollection`) to the session.
When the error collection becomes too large, it seems the data is not stored in the session, presumably due to memory limitations.
I'm facing challenges in handling large error collections and displaying them to users upon import failures.

How can I efficiently handle large error collections during an import process and store them in the session without facing memory constraints in Laravel?
Are there alternative approaches or best practices to manage and display large error collections to users without relying heavily on session storage?
Any guidance or suggestions on handling large error collections in Laravel during imports would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.